# Is it true that, if $f$ is increasing and bounded above, then there is a $ L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)= L$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Is it true that, if $f$ is increasing and bounded above, then  there is a $ L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)= L$?

I know that this is valid for sequences. Is it possible to generalize the result for real-valued functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is bounded above then $L=\sup f$ exists. Let $\epsilon>0$ then by the characterization of the supremum there's $x_0\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$L-\epsilon<f(x_0)\le L$$
so since $f$ is increasing then for all $x\ge x_0$ we have
$$L-\epsilon<f(x)\le L$$
and we get 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the same way. If $f$ is increasing, let $L = \sup\{f(x) \mid x \in \Bbb R\}$ (assuming $f$ is defined in all of $\Bbb R$). Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then exists $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that $L-\epsilon < f(x_0)$. If $x > x_0$, then $$f(x) \geq f(x_0) > L-\epsilon \implies L - f(x) < \epsilon \implies |f(x)- L| < \epsilon.$$